# How to customise entity name casing in EF Core with database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have an existing `EF6` code base, and I'm trying to port that to `EF Core`, and I have an existing database which I cannot erase/modify. So I'm using the following command to scaffold the entity classes from my database

```
Scaffold-DbContext "MyConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

It does generate the `DbContext` and the necessary entities. Now, seems like they have changed the naming conventions (how to name entities, properties & navigation) A LOT and the newly created entities are very different from my existing entities! I couldn't find a way to customise these conventions, so I'm having to manually change the code in many places! (sad!)

One of the changes is: Now EF does not singularize class names from table name. e.g. if table name is 'Accessories', earlier entity class used to be 'Accessory', now it is 'Accessories'!

To fix this, I have used the [IPluralizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.ipluralizer?view=efcore-2.0) interface and used the [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) library to Singularize entity class names.

When I use the `Humanizer` library, it does this

```
"Accessories".Singularize(); //produces "Accessory"
"XMLDetails".Singularize(); //produces "XMLDetail"
```

BUT, in the final entity class created by `EF Core`, the second property name becomes `Xmldetail` ignoring the original casing! Is there a way to retain the original casing through the process of EF Core scaffolding?

*Note: I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` version `2.0.1` with a class library targeting `.NET Standard 2.0`.*

Comment: It's hard to give you a good advice. Eventually try playing with EF Core internals, like replacing [`ICandidateNamingService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.scaffolding.internal.icandidatenamingservice?view=efcore-2.0) by deriving from [`CandidateNamingService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.scaffolding.internal.candidatenamingservice?view=efcore-2.0) class and overriding `GenerateCandidateIdentifier` method.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, it does help. Unfortunately, right now I'm not comfortable changing the internals, especially with "This API may change or be removed in future releases" warnings. I do not intend to change my code again and again in future.

Comment: Sure, it's up to you. Then all you can do is to wait them to provide an option or public extensibility point like `IPluralizer` (who knows when and if they will) and apply your current manual process :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I came to know from the GitHub community that, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10678) in `EF Core 2.0` and it has already been [fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9820) in the repo. **The fix is scheduled to release with `EF Core 2.1`.**

Once the fix is released you can use the `--use-database-names` flag to tell EF to generate names exactly according to the database names like this

```
Scaffold-DbContext "ConnString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models --use-database-names
```

Until that, you can try one of the following tools which gives more/better options than default `EF Core` tools (I have not practically used them yet)

1. [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF-Core-Power-Tools)
2. [EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator)

Comment: use "-usedatabasenames" instead "--use-database-names"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this.

> One of the changes is: Now EF does not singularize class names from table name. e.g. if table name is 'Accessories', earlier entity class used to be 'Accessory', now it is 'Accessories'!

What I know so far, there is an option when connection EF to DB. It does the same output as earlier versions.

Like this: https://dotnetinterviewquestion.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/ut.png

Comment: Can you show a full text showing the process rather than the image. That works well with full framework EF, but I do not think it works for EF Core. Also, singularization is not the main problem, casing is.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I missread EF "Core" :( never worked with that, sorry :/